# Java or Scala RFC5987

Tags: java, scala, playframework, http-headers, encode

What is the easy way to follow [RFC5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) in encoding a HTTP header parameter?

HTTP header parameters seem really, really common, but I can seem to find a good example for doing this in Play (Java or Scala).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaResponse